# How to control variable substitution in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have some user defined variables:

```
SERVER_NAME          myhost.com
THE_HTTP_PROTOCOL    HTTP
LOOP_COUNT           2
```

Then, I use a Recording Controller to capture my browser actions.  Unfortunately, JMeter does more variable substitution than I'd like it to.  For example, it substitutes `${LOOP_COUNT}` into a web site name that contains "2", e.g., `/host${LOOP_COUNT}/somePage`.  My favorite example of over-zealous variable substitution is my `${THE_${THE_HTTP_PROTOCOL}_PROTOCOL}` Header Manager.

Is it possible to make the recording more selective about what variables can be used for substitution?  For example, of the variables I've listed, I'd really only like `SERVER_NAME` to be substituted in.

I'm using JMeter 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by adding a User Defined Variables (UDV) element to my workbench.

[image]

It defined:

```
THE_HTTP_PROTOCOL    someStringThatShouldNeverBeMatched
USER_COUNT           someStringThatShouldNeverBeMatched
```

Then, when I recorded, I did not get the unwanted variable substitutions.

Another option is to break up a monolithic collection of variables into smaller groups using User Defined Variables.  Then, you can disable certain of those smaller groupings when you need to record.  For example, you could put `USER_COUNT` into a "Flow of Control" UDV, and then disable it at recording time as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For now you must disable User Defined Properties during recording.

Maybe you could open a bugzilla request here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

Note that variable substitution works better with Regex Matching checked (HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder component) as it will be much more intelligent.

But ensure if you use it you do not use values (usually short ones) that can be frequently in responses/requests.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Bugzilla.  It appears that bug https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51826 covers my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to substitute variables during recording as the behavior may be flaky.

If you want to parametrize your recorded test it's better to go for

- [HTTP Request Defaults](http://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults) - for host, protocol and any other http-related stuff
- [JMeter Properties](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) and functions like [_*P()*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [_property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) to retrieve them .

Actually I would set host and protocol as properties too as they can be set via command line, via Ant or Maven plugin or any other way of invoking JMeter. Besides properties can be shared across thread groups and variables have local scope.